# Will cmake target_link_libraries() call target_include_directories()?

Tags: cmake

My understanding is that if I want to use a 3rd library, I need the header file path and the link obj path.

in CMake, I think a successful `find_package()` will set 2 variables: `somelib_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `somelib_LIBRARIES`.

But in many case, I only call

```
target_link_libraries(myexe
  ${somelib_LIBRARIES} )
```

and it seems to be sufficient. (`somelib_INCLUDE_DIRS` is not used)

My question is: Is my experience correct? `somelib_INCLUDE_DIRS` is not necessary?

If it's correct, can I say the reason is that `target_link_libraries` calls `target_include_directories` internally?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will cmake target_link_libraries() call target_include_directories()?

*If* `target_link_libraries` is called with a library target name that has `PUBLIC` or `INTERFACE` include directories, *then* `target_link_libraries` will also add those include directories to the target. I.e. INTERFACE properties are "transitive" or are "inherited".

> Is my experience correct? somelib_INCLUDE_DIRS is not necessary?

That 100% just depends on the specific library configuration. *If* the condition described above is satisfied, then yes. If not, `somelib_LIBRARIES` has *libraries* or link flags and not CMake library target names, or those library target names do not have any PUBLIC or INTERFACE include directories, etc...., then not.

*Some* `find_package` configuration files have been rewritten with `add_library(... INTERFACE`. *Some* not. It depends on the specific library CMake configuration. Consult the documentation and source code of the specific library CMake configuration files to know how to use it.

> If it's correct, can I say the reason is that target_link_libraries calls target_include_directories internally?

Yes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `target_include_directory` command isn't directly used as consequence of using `target_link_libraries` with a cmake target. You get similar effects, but afaik the `target_link_libraries` command only modified the `LINK_LIBRARIES` and/or `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` target properties (assuming parameters other than linker flags); The necessary include directories are determined based on this info after the parsing step is done...